# Make optional fields required in certain condition

Tags: jquery, forms

So I have 4 input type text that are **optional** (no obligation to fill in)  but if the user fills in one of them, then I want him to fill them all.

Resume:
- If user fills in 0 input => no obligation, he can leave them blank;
- If user fills in 1< input => **must** fill them all.

How can I do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    var filled = $(this).find("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value.length > 0;
    });

    if (filled.length > 0) {
        alert("Fill 'em all!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xw9pb/

Comment: Thank you for your answer =)! Just one little thing and a question. Question: is it possible to do something similar with a keyup trigger? Thing: when they are all field the "Fill 'em all!" still shows up =/